# Compile Dropwizard Code without migration.xml

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a finalized database in SQL SERVER containing 50+ tables in it and needed to connect it with [Dropwizard Code](http://www.dropwizard.io/).

I am new to JAVA so my conception about [Migrations.xml](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/migrations.html) is it is used to create the tables in database or if any change in database is needed it will be updated through migrations.xml.

So if i don't need any change in database (as told earlier it is finalized).
Can i skip this migrations.xml file?

Need some experts advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are handling your database changes elsewhere, then you have no need for any migration xml files within your dropwizard project. It's an optional module, you don't need to use it. You don't even need to include the `dropwizard-migrations` dependency if you don't want to include database updates in your dropwizard project. You can still connect to your database fine within dropwizard. The docs provide examples using modules `dropwizard-jdbi` and `dropwizard-hibernate`.

To connect to your database, add the appropriate code the your java configuration file and yml config as explained in the docs.

**jdbi**
http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/jdbi.html

**hibernate**
http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/hibernate.html

Comment: That's correct - Migrations have one more feature that I find quite useful though that i'd like to mention. I don't like doing production updates to DB systems automatically, but I use migrations to schema-check my DB from the application on startup. If migrations detects any unrun changes, it prints them to the error log and shuts down again. (Also helps new dev's with setting up an environment since the migrations tell them what is wrong with their setup)